# T-SQL - I want sum for each year os sales (Adventureworks2014)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sum

I'm trying to get total sum base on `total_due` column for the `customerid` where year = some year. but it does not sum correctly for example:

```
USE AdventureWorks2014
go

SELECT
    soh.CustomerID
   ,CONCAT(p.FirstName, ' ', p.LastName) AS [Full Name]
   ,cr.Name AS Country
   ,SUM(soh.TotalDue) AS Total_Sales
   ,YEAR(soh.OrderDate) AS Order_Year
FROM 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
JOIN 
    Sales.SalesTerritory st ON soh.TerritoryID = st.TerritoryID
JOIN 
    Person.CountryRegion cr ON st.CountryRegionCode = cr.CountryRegionCode
JOIN
    Sales.Customer c ON soh.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
JOIN 
    Person.Person p ON c.PersonID = p.BusinessEntityID
WHERE 
    YEAR(soh.OrderDate) = 2011
    AND soh.CustomerID = 30100
GROUP BY 
    soh.CustomerID
    ,p.FirstName
    ,p.LastName
    ,cr.Name
    ,soh.OrderDate
```

[image]

Comment: What's wrong with the values? I notice you display `YEAR(soh.OrderDate)` in the `SELECT`, however, you put `soh.OrderDate` in the `GROUP BY`. Is *that* the problem? The year of an order, and the date of an order aren't the same. Seems like atypographical error to me.

Comment: i want to have just one row with sum not 2. one record with sum data for each year for each customer.

Comment: ahhh ok i got it it should be GROUP BY soh.CustomerID
  ,p.FirstName
  ,p.LastName
  ,cr.Name
  ,YEAR(soh.OrderDate) Thank you, it was so simple... :) i stuck there for like hour

Comment: Yes, you need to `GROUP BY` the groupings you want the data to be grouped into (unsurprisingly :) ).